# Making a process scheduling simulator for SPN (shortest process next)

Tags: c, scheduling

I am making a simulator for SPN in c. right now the code also does FCFS and SRT, but those work fine. i think it is the way it calculates start times but i haven't been able to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>   

#define MAX_PROCESSES 100

// Define a struct to represent a process
typedef struct {
    char name;
    int arrival_time;
    int service_time;
    int start_time;
    int finish_time;
    int wait_time;
    int turnaround_time;
} Process;

// Define a function to simulate the processes using the SPN scheduling algorithm
void spn(Process* processes, int num_processes) {
    int current_time = 0;
    int remaining_times[MAX_PROCESSES];
    int completed_processes = 0;

    // initialize remaining times array
    for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        remaining_times[i] = processes[i].service_time;
    }

    while (completed_processes < num_processes) {
        int shortest_time = INT_MAX;
        int shortest_index = -1;

        // find process with shortest remaining time
        for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
            if (processes[i].arrival_time <= current_time && remaining_times[i] < shortest_time && remaining_times[i] > 0) {
                shortest_time = remaining_times[i];
                shortest_index = i;
            }
        }

        if (shortest_index == -1) {
            current_time++;
            continue;
        }

        // calculate start time
        if (current_time < processes[shortest_index].arrival_time) {
            processes[shortest_index].start_time = processes[shortest_index].arrival_time;
            current_time = processes[shortest_index].arrival_time;
        } else {
            processes[shortest_index].start_time = current_time;
        }

        // execute process for 1 unit of time
        remaining_times[shortest_index]--;
        current_time++;

        // check if process is completed
        if (remaining_times[shortest_index] == 0) {
            // calculate finish time, wait time, and turnaround time
            processes[shortest_index].finish_time = current_time;
            processes[shortest_index].wait_time = processes[shortest_index].start_time - processes[shortest_index].arrival_time;
            processes[shortest_index].turnaround_time = processes[shortest_index].finish_time - processes[shortest_index].arrival_time;

            completed_processes++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int num_processes;
    char name;
    int arrival_time;
    int service_time;
    char temp;
    int choice;

    // Read the number of processes from the user
    printf("Enter the number of processes: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_processes);

    // Allocate memory for the array of processes
    Process* processes = (Process*)malloc(num_processes * sizeof(Process));

    // Read the process information from the user
    for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &temp);
        printf("Enter the name, arrival time, and service time of process %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%c %d %d", &name, &arrival_time, &service_time);

        // Copy the process information to the array of processes
        processes[i].name = name;
        processes[i].arrival_time = arrival_time;
        processes[i].service_time = service_time;

        // Initialize the remaining fields
        processes[i].start_time = -1;
        processes[i].finish_time = -1;
        processes[i].wait_time = -1;
        processes[i].turnaround_time = -1;
    }
    
     // Prompt the user to choose between FCFS and SPN
     printf("Enter 1 for FCFS, 2 for SPN, or 3 for SRT: ");
     scanf("%d", &choice);
 
     if (choice == 1) {
       // Sort the processes by arrival time (FCFS)
       fcfs_sort(processes, num_processes);
 
       // Simulate the processes using the FCFS scheduling algorithm
       fcfs_simulate(processes, num_processes);
 
       // Print the results for FCFS
       printf("FCFS\n");
       printf("%-8s %-14s %-12s %-10s %-11s %-9s %-15s\n", "Process", "Arrival Time", "Service Time", "Start Time", "Finish Time", "Wait Time", "Turnaround Time");
       for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
         printf("%-8c %-14d %-12d %-10d %-11d %-9d %-15d\n", processes[i].name, processes[i].arrival_time, processes[i].service_time, processes[i].start_time, processes[i].finish_time, processes[i].wait_time, processes[i].turnaround_time);
       }
 
       // Draw the Gantt chart for FCFS
       draw_gantt_chart(processes, num_processes);
     }
      else if (choice == 2) {
         // Sort the processes by shortest processing time (SPN)
         spn(processes, num_processes);
 
         // Print the results for SPN
         printf("SPN\n");
         printf("%-8s %-14s %-12s %-10s %-11s %-9s %-15s\n", "Process", "Arrival Time", "Service Time", "Start Time", "Finish Time", "Wait Time", "Turnaround Time");
         for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
           printf("%-8c %-14d %-12d %-10d %-11d %-9d %-15d\n", processes[i].name, processes[i].arrival_time, processes[i].service_time, processes[i].start_time, processes[i].finish_time, processes[i].wait_time, processes[i].turnaround_time);
         }
 
       // Draw the Gantt chart for SPN
       draw_gantt_chart(processes, num_processes);
     }
    else if (choice == 3) {
       
         // Simulate the processes using the SRT scheduling algorithm
         srt(processes, num_processes);
 
         // Print the results for SRT
         printf("SRT\n");
         printf("%-8s %-14s %-12s %-10s %-11s %-9s %-15s\n", "Process", "Arrival Time", "Service Time", "Start Time", "Finish Time", "Wait Time", "Turnaround Time");
         for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
           printf("%-8c %-14d %-12d %-10d %-11d %-9d %-15d\n", processes[i].name, processes[i].arrival_time, processes[i].service_time, processes[i].start_time, processes[i].finish_time, processes[i].wait_time, processes[i].turnaround_time);
         }
 
       // Draw the Gantt chart for SRT
       draw_gantt_chart(processes, num_processes);
     }
     
     
     
     // Free the memory
     free(processes);

    return 0;

}
```

The input is according to this table:
Process Arrival Time Service Time
A         0            3
B         2            6
C         4            4
D         6            5
E         8            2

and the output should end up as:
Process Arrival Time Service Time Start Time Finish Time Wait Time Turnaround Time
A              0            3          0           3         0          3
B              2            6          3           9         1          7
C              4            4          11          15        7          11
D              6            5          15          20        5          14
E              8            2          9           11        1          3

but I am getting:
Process Arrival Time Service Time Start Time Finish Time Wait Time Turnaround Time
A              0            3          2           3         2          3
B              2            6          14          15        12         13
C              4            4          7           8         3          4
D              6            5          19          20        13         14
E              8            2          9           10        1          2

i have been fiddling with the spn function but it hasnt yielded anything but more wrong answers

Comment: `undefined reference to \`fcfs_sort' \`fcfs_simulate' \`draw_gantt_chart' \`srt'`

Answer (score 0):

> i think it is the way it calculates start times

Indeed this is the reason why start times are wrong - they are wrongly recalculated every unit of time when the process runs, rather than set once at the *start*, like:

```
        // calculate start time
        if (processes[shortest_index].start_time < 0)
            processes[shortest_index].start_time = current_time;
```

But that's not all - the *Finish Time* is also wrong, because you programmed a preemptive algorithm, while [SPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next) is non-preemptive.

Comment: Ironically; calculating the start time and end time wrong is probably a lot more realistic (it's not like either of them can be known by an OS in advance ;-).